# Is there any good review paper on the density matrix renormalization group (DMRG) method?

Tags: reference-request, magnetism, dmrg

I would appreciate if someone could recommend me good review literature on the density matrix renormalization group (DMRG) method, especially for magnetic systems.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- [**2003**: Book chapter](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0303557)  by Karen Hallberg.
- [**2004**: Reviews of Modern Physics](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0409292) by Ulrich Schollwoeck (2818 current citations).
- [**2006**: Advances in Physics](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00018730600766432) by Karen Hallberg.
- [**2008**: JCTN:](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0603842) by Gabriele De Chiara and co-workers.
- [**2011**: ARPC:](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-physchem-032210-103338) by Garnet Chan and Sandeep Sharma (426 current citations).
- [**2014**: The European Physical Journal D](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.2040) by Sebastian Wouters and Dimitri Van Neck.
- [**2014**: IJQC](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/qua.24808) by Takeshi Yanai and co-workers.
- [**2015**: JCP](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.4905329) by Roberto Olivares-Amaya and co-workers.

---

**There is also [this website](http://quattro.phys.sci.kobe-u.ac.jp/dmrg.html) which attempts (seemingly very successfully!) to track every DMRG, MPS, TPS, MERA, and/or general Tensor Network paper *ever*.**

Comment: I vote for 2004: Reviews of Modern Physics by Ulrich Schollwoeck, which is long but comprehensive.

Comment: Schollwöck is actually 2005, https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.77.259

Comment: on arXiv it says "accepted by Rev. Mod. Phys. in July 2004; scheduled to appear in the January 2005 issue". Perhaps I can change my answer so that it says 2005, but one should know that this review covers only material up to 2004.

Answer (score 6):

There's two later review articles by Schollwöck that weren't in Nike's excellent list:

- **2011:** [Phil. Trans. R. Soc. A (2011) 369, 2643–2661](http://doi.org/10.1098/rsta.2010.0382)
- **2011:** [Annals of Physics 326 (2011) 96–192](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aop.2010.09.012)